# Is there a difference between "if let" and "if"?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Code:

```rust
let x = Some(3);
if x == Some(3) {
    println!("if case");
}
if let Some(3) = x {
    println!("if let case");
}
```

Result:

```
if case
if let case
```

Why do rust programmers use "if let" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `if let`, you can use pattern matching to decompose `x` into parts:

```
let x = Some(3);
if let Some(v) = x {
    println!("{}", v); // prints 3
}
```

The same thing with `if` is inelegant:

```
let x = Some(3);
if x.is_some() {
    println!("{}", x.unwrap()); // not recommended
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=31e122da989d6e427206a1014fc28f11))